# Formating window without affecting Ubuntu

Tags: window, format

I have installed Ubuntu 10.04 with the help of vmware workstation. Now I want to format window xp without affecting Ubuntu and ns 2.29 which is installed in Ubuntu, is it possible?

Comment: Is the Ubuntu 10.04 the server version?  If not then it's not supported and I suggest you install a supported version also Windows is off topic on this site and XP is end of life.

Answer (score 2):

1. Just backup *.vmdk ie hard disk image files created by VMWare.
2. Now when you reinstall VMWare upon format create a new Virtual Machine with preferably the **exact** same configurations.
3. When VMWare asks to create the Virtual Hard Disk, Choose existing VMDK file.

Backed up Ubuntu will boot.